# How to update a value in a 4D Tensorflow Variable by index / indices?

Tags: tensorflow

Lets's assume I have a 4D tensor and I want to change one element in it:

```
[[[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]]
```

to

```
[[[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]]
```

Any ideas how this can be achieved easily? I am aware of [tf.scatter_update](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.8/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_update) but it seems quite performance bulky because a whole dimension needs to be changed when doing an update.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that [tf.scatter_nd_update](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.8/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd_update) is the operation for updating individual values. [tf.scatter_update](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.8/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_update) on the other hand, will only update rows/slices.